# ELK Monitoring deploy roles with index unavailibvility

Tags: elastic-stack, elk

I deployed ELK Monitoring Cluster (ELK with feature of monitoring enabled ) and I have couple of other clusters with metricbeat connecting to elasticsearch on it.

I would like to implement rule that when in index thereis no recent data - it will trigger an alert.
Is it some dedicated rule for it ? I checked rules and alerts and didn't find anything related